# Multiple or in if statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing an if statement that has multiple or in it. If `validate1` returns true, it doesn't execute `validate2` or `validate3`. But I need it to check `validate2` and `validate3`.

I can't use `&&` here, it is not satisfying my expectation as I tried. And I didn't want to write multiple if

Is there any way to solved this with one if statement?

```
if (this.validate1(x, y) || this.validate2(a, b) || this.validate3(c, d))
{ }
else {
  showError();
}
```

I tried with and situations. Every validation is returning an error, with and if one of them is passing the validation then it's going to next step. This is not what i want.

And i write something wrong `validate2` or `validate3`to be checked too.

Comment: Write out a working version with nested if statements so we know exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
var val2 = this.validate2(a, b);
if (this.validate1(x, y) || val2 || this.validate3(c, d))
{ }
else {
  showError();
}
```

This way `validate2` will always get called without changing the logic.